# Primeng Table - is it possible to combine scrolling in both directions AND virtual scrolling?

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable, virtualscroll

Is it possible to use the table with scrolling in both directions AND virtual scrolling?

E.G. if I use:

```
<p-table
    [columns]="startColumns"
    [value]="data"
    [scrollable]="true" 
    scrollHeight="400px"
    scrollDirection="both">
```

Everything works as expected but as soon as I add the virtual scrolling like:

```
   <p-table
    [columns]="startColumns"
    [value]="data"
    [scrollable]="true" 
    scrollHeight="400px"
    scrollDirection="both"
    [rows]="100"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [virtualRowHeight]="40"
    >
```

the horizontal Scrollbar is gone.

Answer (score 0):

remove `[rows]="100"`

and instead of `[virtualRowHeight]="40"` use `[virtualScrollItemSize]="40"`